# Google Play Games SDK for iOS giving strange errors when using Snapshots

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to use Google's Play Games SDK for iOS. Upon signing my user in and then running one of their straight-forward methods:

```
[GPGSnapshotMetadata
     openWithFileName:saveStoreName
     conflictPolicy:GPGSnapshotConflictPolicyRemoteWins
     completionHandler:^(GPGSnapshotMetadata *snapshot,
                         NSString *conflictId,
                         GPGSnapshotMetadata *conflictingSnapshotBase,
                         GPGSnapshotMetadata *conflictingSnapshotRemote,
                         NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"We got here. It must be an actual miracle.");
     }];
```

instead of ever being sent to the completion handler, I get this error:

```
2014-07-13 22:01:33.700 MegaBits[6931:f007] WARNING: Returning empty data: id not found
2014-07-13 22:01:33.707 MegaBits[6931:f007] VERBOSE: Snapshot cache fully expired: refreshing all.
2014-07-13 22:01:33.892 MegaBits[6931:8d07] VERBOSE: Request had Apiary Status Code: 7
2014-07-13 22:01:33.894 MegaBits[6931:8d07] VERBOSE: Parsed error<http_code: 403, domain: usageLimits, reason: accessNotConfigured>
```

And those last 2 lines repeat a number of times.

I'm not sure what any of this means. It doesn't appear to be documented anyway, and so far as I can tell, Apiary is an API-generating startup. This error only comes from running this method. Commenting it out results in my code continuing to run smoothly. Apiary also isn't a service I'm using anywhere else.

We also haven't even approached 1% of our quota, so we're not being rate limited.

Comment: Have you ever enabled the proper api on Google API Console(https://console.developers.google.com)?

Comment: I have now! So here's how to fix this issue... You have to go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish > [Your game name], and then scroll down and ensure that "Saved Games" is set to on. Boom.